# Need help optimizing query counts on distinct columns based on other columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Essentially I have a table comprised of the following columns:

|Time|CompanyID|ProductType|ApplicationType|CustomerNumber|SessionId

Essentially I want to have the

1) total distinct counts of customerNumber for each product type for each company

Right now I have about ~4000 companies with about 3 products each and a total of about 130,000 records. My code is really inefficient and takes forever to run

Below is my current code:

```
companies = list(final_table.select(final_table.CompanyId).distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())
  for c in companies:

  company_detail = final_table.filter(final_table.CompanyId == c)


  products = list(company_detail.select(company_detail.OriginalModule).distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())

  for p in products:

      unique_user_count = company_detail.filter(company_detail.Product == p).select(company_detail.CustomerNumber).distinct().count()
      total_views = company_detail.filter(company_detail.ProductType == p).count()
```

It runs but it's incredibly slow and inefficient, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `groupby` and `agg` for DataFrame:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
company_detail.groupBy(["CompanyId", "ProductType"]).agg(F.countDistinct(company_detail['customerNumber']))
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can do this way.

just use `distinct`, `groupBy` and `count` and optional `orderBy` if you want

```
df.select("CompanyId","ProductType","customerNumber").distinct().groupBy("CompanyId","ProductType","customerNumber").count().orderBy("CompanyId").show()
```

---

**Details**

---

> Raw data

```
df.select('DOB','last_name','First_name').show(20, False)


+----------+---------+----------+
|DOB       |last_name|First_name|
+----------+---------+----------+
|1986-02-09|mon      |Jo        |
|1976-02-09|boss     |hugo      |
|1986-02-09|mon      |Jose      |
|1976-02-09|boss     |hugo      |
|1976-02-09|boss     |hugo      |
|1986-02-09|mon      |Jo        |
|1976-02-09|boss     |hugo      |
|1986-02-09|mon      |Jose      |
|1976-02-09|boss     |hugo      |
|1986-02-09|mon      |Jo        |
|1976-02-09|boss     |hugo      |
|1986-02-09|mon      |Jose      |
|1976-02-09|boss     |hugo      |
|1976-09-09|battle   |chris     |
|1976-09-09|battle   |chris     |
|1986-02-09|mon      |Jo        |
|1976-02-09|boss     |hugo      |
|1986-02-09|mon      |Jo        |
|1976-02-09|boss     |hugo      |
+----------+---------+----------+
```

> group by counts with duplicates

```
df.groupBy('DOB','last_name','First_name').count().orderBy('DOB').show()

+----------+---------+----------+-----+
|       DOB|last_name|First_name|count|
+----------+---------+----------+-----+
|1976-02-09|     boss|      hugo|    9|
|1976-09-09|   battle|     chris|    2|
|1986-02-09|      mon|      Jose|    3|
|1986-02-09|      mon|        Jo|    5|
+----------+---------+----------+-----+
```

> group by count with **out duplicate**

```
df.select('DOB','last_name','First_name').distinct().groupBy('DOB','last_name','First_name').count().orderBy("DOB").show()

+----------+---------+----------+-----+
|       DOB|last_name|First_name|count|
+----------+---------+----------+-----+
|1976-02-09|     boss|      hugo|    1|
|1976-09-09|   battle|     chris|    1|
|1986-02-09|      mon|      Jose|    1|
|1986-02-09|      mon|        Jo|    1|
+----------+---------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: hope this answers your question. you are very welcome :)